# Are Google affiliate ads automatically included if you use Google AdSense?

Tags: google-adsense

If you're running Google AdSense on your site will it automatically include Google Affiliate ads as a 3rd party network if it thinks that will optimize revenue? Or do you have to explicitly setup Google Affiliates and opt in and setup the relevant JavaScript etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must set up Google Affiliate links separately.  They are not automatically included in your Adsense ad code.